# What tuning needs to be done in Windows for Jmeter load Drivers

Tags: performance, jmeter, load-testing

When I use Jmeter or any other load tool in Linux, I always tune the OS in the Load Drivers to make sure they are not a bottleneck. Things I typically do:

1. Make sure anonymous ports go from 5k to 65k (60k ports available)
2. Can configure Linux with TCP_TW_REUSE to minimize sockets in TimeWait
3. ulimit the user that will run the test in terms of open files and max processes

Can somebody please share what tuning is needed in Windows for load drivers to get maximum throughput? I'm new to the use of Windows as the OS for load drivers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. It's configurable via registry: `MaxUserPort` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\ Services\TCPIP\Parameters`
2. It's configurable via registry: `TcpTimedWaitDelay` key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters`
3. Windows doesn't have hard limits on open file handles, it's not applicable

References:

- [Settings that can be Modified to Improve Network Performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/settings-that-can-be-modified-to-improve-network-performance)
- [Configuring the Windows port in Jmeter when number of Request is high](http://programmersqueue.blogspot.com/2016/01/configuring-windows-port-in-jmeter-when.html)
- [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)